# Basics Method Override

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, methods

First of all, Sorry. I'm not good at English.
Hi. I'm beginner of iOS.

To learn Objective-c for the first time
Define the class name and method name in the header file and declare the class object created above in the main.m file on implementation details. M calling the method does.

```
[NewPoint SetPoint: 3];
[NewPoint print];
```

But iOS studied, I suddenly was wondering iOS studied.

Without calling the method directly from the `main.m`, `appdelegate.m` method override you if you do not like this `[NewPoint SetPoint:3]` that is the exact reason why I wonder.

Why Running just override method not using [NewPoint SetPoint:3] like this.

Comment: I think iPatel was asking for something a bit more extensive. Have you created a class of your own? If so, please post the header and implementation of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For learning purpose it was taught to create class in main.m itself.

But in real programming world, you follow classes which are a blue print, so these are created separately for full use throughout the application and other classes/objects are able to use them.

Classes make your code separate from different classes. AppDelegate is one such class which comes initially with a project.

Later on you will make your own classes like Person, Employee, Box etc each one having their own properties, behaviours etc.

What I feel is in your training you were taught to create a class and object as NewPoint, later it was created in AppDelegate. Now you can try to use a differenct class called NewPoint and make an object of that inside AppDelegate and use it.